# Use Class “Name” Instead of “Name”

Tags: javascript

Im having trouble understanding how to solution the following code so that its using "Class Name" instead of "Name".

For example: I when you click 9am I would like only and all other 9AM elements disabled.

Thank you for any insight.

```html
 <script>
    function ckChange(el) {
        var ckName = document.getElementsByTagName('input');

        for (var i = 0, c; c = ckName[i]; i++) {

            if (ckName[i].type == "checkbox" && el.className === "9AM") {
            
                
                c.disabled = !(!el.checked || c === el);
                
            }
             
        }
    }
</script>
<tr>
    <td><input class="9AM" data="9AM" type="checkbox" name="progress1" id="progress1" value="1" tabIndex="1" onClick="ckChange(this)">9AM</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td><input class="9AM" data="9AM" type="checkbox" name="progress1" id="progress2" value="1" tabIndex="1" onClick="ckChange(this)">9AM</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td><input class="10AM" data="10AM" type="checkbox" name="progress1" id="progress3" value="1" tabIndex="1" onClick="ckChange(this)">10AM</td>
</tr>

<tr>
    <td><input class="10AM" data="10AM" type="checkbox" name="progress1" id="progress3" value="1" tabIndex="1" onClick="ckChange(this)">10AM</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td><input class="11AM" data="11AM" type="checkbox" name="progress1" id="progress4" value="1" tabIndex="1" onClick="ckChange(this)">Test 4</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td><input class="11AM" data="11AM" type="text" name="progress1" id="progress4" tabIndex="1" onClick="ckChange(this)">Input</td>
</tr>
```

Comment: this is way too less information. How should the checkboxes behave exactly?

Comment: Whatever you want to do, you'll probably find [`document.getElementsByClassName()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName) and/or [`document.querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If what you're looking to do is disable any other elements that have the same className than you need to update your if statement a bit. You're checking only the element that was passed into the function when I think you mean to do a comparisson of the element that was checked with all other elements className.

```
function ckChange(el) {
  var ckName = document.getElementsByTagName("input");

  for (var i = 0, c; (c = ckName[i]); i++) {
    console.log(el.className)
    if (ckName[i].type == "checkbox" && ckName[i].className === el.className) {
      c.disabled = !(!el.checked || c === el);
    }
  }
}
```

Here's a functioning codepen: https://codepen.io/orunnals/pen/qBEabgq

Comment: Thanks so much for taking the time to help! Learned a lot here.

Comment: Great! If my answer was what you were looking for please accept it as the answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can group elements with the same class name and then, when a checkbox is checked, disable all the elements in its group.
Here is an example:

```js
const groupClasses = ['9AM', '10AM', '11AM'];
const groups = groupClasses.map((cls) => {
  const elms = document.getElementsByClassName(cls);
  return Array.from(elms);
});

groups.forEach((group) => {
  group.forEach((elm) => {
    elm.addEventListener('change', () => {
      group.filter(e => e !== elm).forEach((e) => {
        e.disabled = elm.checked;
      });
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<tr>
  <td><input class="9AM" data="9AM" type="checkbox" name="" id="progress1" value="1" tabIndex="1">9AM</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td><input class="9AM" data="9AM" type="checkbox" name="" id="progress2" value="1" tabIndex="1">9AM</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td><input class="10AM" data="10AM" type="checkbox" name="" id="progress3" value="1" tabIndex="1">10AM</td>
</tr>

<tr>
  <td><input class="10AM" data="10AM" type="checkbox" name="" id="progress3" value="1" tabIndex="1">10AM</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td><input class="11AM" data="11AM" type="checkbox" name="" id="progress4" value="1" tabIndex="1">Test 4</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td><input class="11AM" data="11AM" type="text" name="" id="progress4" tabIndex="1">Input</td>
</tr>
```

Comment: This is doing exactly what his code do.. Did you run the code Snippet on his?

Comment: @GustavoAGarcia No it is not, my snippet only disables checkboxes that have the same class as the clicked one, the OP's disables all of them.

Answer (score 0):

check current element class with all other class
**ckName[i].className === el.className**

```html
<script>
    function ckChange(el) {
        var ckName = document.getElementsByTagName('input');

        for (var i = 0, c; c = ckName[i]; i++) {
       // console.log(ckName[i]);
            if (ckName[i].type == "checkbox" && ckName[i].className === el.className) {
            ckName[i].disabled = true;
                
                //c.disabled = !(!el.checked || c === el);
                
            }
             
        }
    }
</script>
<tr>
    <td><input class="9AM" data="9AM" type="checkbox" name="" id="progress1" value="1" tabIndex="1" onClick="ckChange(this)">9AM</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td><input class="9AM" data="9AM" type="checkbox" name="" id="progress2" value="1" tabIndex="1" onClick="ckChange(this)">9AM</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td><input class="10AM" data="10AM" type="checkbox" name="" id="progress3" value="1" tabIndex="1" onClick="ckChange(this)">10AM</td>
</tr>

<tr>
    <td><input class="10AM" data="10AM" type="checkbox" name="" id="progress3" value="1" tabIndex="1" onClick="ckChange(this)">10AM</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td><input class="11AM" data="11AM" type="checkbox" name="" id="progress4" value="1" tabIndex="1" onClick="ckChange(this)">Test 4</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td><input class="11AM" data="11AM" type="text" name="" id="progress4" tabIndex="1" onClick="ckChange(this)">Input</td>
</tr>
```